# how to add an crypto algorithm to linux crypto api

Tags: linux, cryptography, kernel

I need to add a specific crypto algorithm to the Linux crypto API, so I can see it in the /proc/crypto and use it in IPsec ESP. is there any template for developing a crypto algorithm for the Linux kernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the kernel Crypto [API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/crypto/index.html) (but I dont recommend rolling out your own crypto algorithms). You register your crypto algorithm using this function call.

```
int crypto_register_alg(struct crypto_alg *alg);
```

But make sure you correctly filled the `struct crypto_alg` first.
`struct crypto_alg` [Link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/crypto.h#L469) holds info about your algorithm which also contain `struct cipher_alg` [Link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/crypto.h#L242) which in turn contain pointers to the encrypt and decrypt functions.